# Finding parentheses with % in vim across lines

Tags: vim, vi

In the following text block, starting at 1 or 3, and pressing `%` in normal mode in `vim`, finds the pair of matching parentheses, and toggles between them if you press `%` again. Starting at 1 finds the closing `)` first. Starting at 3 finds the opening `(` first.   This is all OK and useful.

```
Some lines 1 with (stuff 2 in
matching 3 parentheses)
```

However, starting at 2 and pressing `%` finds nothing. What's going on?

*Update*: other commands such as `vib` can find the `(...)` block from either 2 or 3 (but not 1) which is one way around the limitation, but still curious...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually the documented and expected behavior, from `:help %`.

> Find the next item *in this line* after or under the cursor and jump to its match.

I do not know of any way to make `%` search beyond the current line.  You could try `])` and its relatives as a workaround.